# Is it possible to create plugins for the FirefoxOS Music Player?

Tags: firefox-os

I would like to create a lastfm-scrobble plugin for the FirefoxOS music player. The plugin would detect that a new song is played and transmit the played song's name and the user-id to lastfm. The plugin has a simple UI where the user can enter its username and password.

The question now is: is it possible to extend the media player with plugins like described above?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the default apps for Firefox OS (which are also called gaia apps) do not have a pluggable architecture. However, these applications are an open source project and so you are welcome to fork the music app, add the scrobbling ability, and submit your changes as a github pull request. If they don't accept your changes, you can still submit your fork to the firefox marketplace, since I am sure there are plenty of users who would also like this feature.

The repository for Firefox OS apps is here:
https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/

Here is a wiki page to get you started with gaia app development:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developing_Gaia

And if you have any questions along the way, you can always get live support on IRC: #gaia channel on irc.mozilla.org:6697.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's possible, despite what Michael says :-), the only problem is that you will need a certified application, so you cannot distribute through the marketplace.

First thing you need is add a `connections` section to your manifest file and add the `mediacomms` connection in there. [Example](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/5506794a3ee1ea1a21ed09762a46dd3ddadbdff6/apps/system/manifest.webapp#L103).

Now you want to copy the [iac_handler.js](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/5506794a3ee1ea1a21ed09762a46dd3ddadbdff6/shared/js/iac_handler.js) file into your project and add it to your .html file.

Then you can add a listener in JavaScript to get media information:

```
window.addEventListener('iac-mediacomms', function(ev) {
    var message = event.detail;
    switch (message.type) {
         case 'nowplaying':
         // message.data has { title, artist, picture }
         break;
    }
});
```

Comment: If the goal is to give other firefox OS users the ability to scrobble, creating a new certified app is not really workable (only Mozilla can distribute certified apps).

Comment: If the goal is to do this only for yourself, you might as well hard code this into the music app, and not worry about IAC overhead. Also, the IAC (Inter-App Communication) API is subject to change, and shouldn't be relied on for 3rd party app devs just yet: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.gaia/XvU-GhODxD0